# Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome: Nvidia Prime problem when switching to Intel Mode

Tags: nvidia, gnome, graphics, gdm, nvidia-prime

I have Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with `nvidia-384` and `nvidia-prime` packages installed using PPA `ppa:graphics-drivers`. After installation, my default desktop manager changed from gdm3 to lightdm, and I fixed it by reinstalling gdm package. After then, my system worked fine using nvidia drivers (except the fact that after resuming the system, my background goes white). Later, I wanted to use nvidia PRIME to switch my Intel card, however, after doing so, I could no longer login my Gnome Session. I had to use `prime-select nvidia` from TTY to be able to login.

My question is how can I fix this issue? Is it a bug related to GNOME (most likely), if it is so, is there anything I can do?

PS: The same issue happens with 17.04 as well, and Unity has never exhibited such behavior.

Comment: Check my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966913/boot-with-nvidia-or-intel-driver-loaded/971304#971304 Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with Gnome Ubuntu 16.04. I think I found a workaround.

At login open terminal:

1. `sudo prime-select intel`
2. `systemctl restart display-manager`
3. Log in and go.

I am not sure if the power savings are there yet. Trying to confirm.